# regexp: выделение из текста целых предложений, содержащих заданные слова

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, полнотекстовый-поиск

подскажите каким регулярным выражением из текста, содержащего много предложений можно выделить предложения, содержащие хотя бы одно слово `#T#`

Comment: Попробуйте [таким образом](https://regex101.com/r/CBPy5r/2): `/(?=.|^)[^.\^]*\bWORD\b[^.]*(.|$)/gmi`, где `WORD` - искомое слово

Comment: @Deonis, работает, правда для `#T#` из-за `\b` пришлось извратнуться `#\bT\b#` и еще VSCode говорил что в `[^.\^]` экранирование избыточно

Comment: `(?=.|^)` и `(.|$)` не имеют в этом выражении смысла. `\b` в `#\bT\b#` вообще не нужны. Нет поддержки аббревиатур, а также восклицательных и вопросительных предложений.

Comment: `text.split(/[\.\?\!][\s$]/).filter((x) => x.includes('#T#'))`